# Is it possible to config an array in a nested object in grunt options?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to write a small plugin and I want the user to be able to input an array into a nested object in grunt config, something like:

```
myTask: {
    default: {
        options: {
        name: "someName"
        deploy: {
            envs: ["dev", "staging", "prod"]
        }
    }
    }
}
```

In my task I'm trying to grab `this.options.deploy.envs` but it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Not seen this style of plugin configuration before. Might be wiser to follow existing conventions for multi tasks:

```
myTask: {
    deploy: {
        options: {
            name: "someName",
            envs: ["dev", "staging", "prod"]
        }
    },
    development: {
        options: {
            name: "othertarget",
            envs: ["dev"]
        }
    }
}
```

In any case, you are missing a comma after "someName".